# css file rule apply to this class

Tags: css

I have this label within website:

```
<nav class="exodus-nav-left-right exodus-content-block exodus-content-block-compact exodus-clearfix">
```

for example want to add the rule to be met in this condition is:
visibility: hidden;

as I have to put in the CSS file?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use full sentences please.  'as I have to put in the CSS file?' is not a question. Neither is ' for example want to add the rule to be met...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it seems that its not a "Label"

and if you want to hide element, you can do so by using the `display` property.

```
.exodus-content-block {
 display:none;
}
```

If there are other elements with same class then you can narrow down your rule by using the whole class attribute value as below..

```
.exodus-nav-left-right.exodus-content-block.exodus-content-block-compact.exodus-clearfix {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the inline styling.

example

```
<nav class="exodus-nav-left-right exodus-content-block exodus-content-block-compact exodus-clearfix" style="visibility:hidden">
```

Or you can write as css class and add in the code

```
<style>.hiddenvis{ visibility:hidden}</style>
<nav class="exodus-nav-left-right exodus-content-block exodus-content-block-compact exodus-clearfix hiddenvis "/>
```

but you got to make sure other classes used here do not override your hidden functionality